# How to run powershell commands in remote computers using AWS Lambda C# .Net Core 2.1

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, powershell-core

How to run powershell commands in remote computers using AWS Lambda C# .Net Core 2.1 ?

Added the nuget package https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Management.Automation/6.1.0-rc.1

Comment: where's the [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking for. Please read- https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and provide a [MCVE]